# Strange behavior with '_' (underscore) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

Just curious about it.

If you open the IRB and type `_`, you'll get `nil` as response:

```
irb(main):001:0> _
=> nil
```

And you can modify its value:

```
irb(main):002:0> _ = 'some value'
irb(main):003:0> _
=> "some value"
```

But if you create a new variable with `_`, its value is modified:

```
irb(main):004:0> foo_bar = 'other value'
irb(main):005:0> _
=> "other value"
```

Why? Is this a design decision?

Comment: It's actually a handy feature. If you want to save the results of your last operation: `a = _`. I often use `irb` as a handy calculator, so you can easily chain things: `_ / 1e6` for example.

Comment: Some more fun meanings for the underscore are presented [Here](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/33-too-expressive.html#underscore-4-syntactical-meanings) such as a visual separator (`1_000_000`) or an ignored parameter `object.each {|_, v| ...}`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`irb` uses `_` to refer to the value of last calculated expression. So you will see `_` changed even if you don't use it in the previous line :)

Comment: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/342527837/console-tip-retrieve-the-last-return-value-with

Answer (score 17):

Within irb, `_` returns the result of the previous operation. So on opening a new irb session `_` will equal nil as there was no previous operation

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > 4
 => 4 
2.0.0p353 :002 > 3 + _
 => 7
```